# What version of Apple TV is required for a HomePod mini stereo pair to work?

Tags: audio, appletv, airplay, homepod

I have two HomePod minis configured as a stereo pair, that is not recognized by my Apple TV. Instead I see each individual HomePod in the audio settings for the TV and can only select and play through one at a time. I have a very old Apple TV (a replacement is on order) and also a very old AirPort Extreme Base Station (also about to be replaced).

What version of Apple TV is required for a HomePod mini stereo pair to work?

Answer (score 1):

HomePod stereo pairs work with **Apple TV 4K** and **HomePod or HomePod mini**. When using it with HomePod mini, Dolby Atmos 5.1/7.1 surround sound are not supported.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207705

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [Home Theatre Audio](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207705) does not currently work with HomePod mini (just HomePod). It also seems to require Apple TV 4K. The benefit of this feature is that you can set your Apple TV audio output to permanently use the HomePod pair.

But you should be able to (manually) Airplay to a pair of HomePod Mini’s with an Apple TV that supports tvOS 14 (an assumption, based on its [support of being an audio hub](https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/play-audio-throughout-your-home-atvb50fb1c50/14.0/tvos/14.0)): this would mean Apple TV HD or Apple TV 4K.

If you’re buying a new Apple TV and you’re interested in using your HomePod Mini’s as your permanent tv speakers, I would suggest getting the Apple TV 4K with the assumption that Apple will eventually add Home Theatre Audio support for the HomePod Mini’s.

Comment: Home Theater audio is not the same as a simple stereo pair. I just finally googled for this and there are tons of examples of using a stereo pair with Apple TV like this one: https://johnsherrod.net/this-is-what-its-like-to-use-two-homepod-minis-as-your-home-theater-speakers-b1a0b5dbc423?gi=8389addadb69

Comment: @jimtut Isn’t that what I mentioned in the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: So the minimum requirement for using a stereo pair is one of the recent Apple TV models? (I shouldn’t expect my old one to work.)

Comment: @orome that’s my assumption, because I think it’s the OS version that allows for stereo pairs.

Comment: It sounds like I should return my HomePod minis. The Apple Store promotional description is misleading.